# Checking the activity of AWS S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to create a web interface to display the usage of my team's AWS S3 buckets. Whenever a member pushes files to a bucket, the status in the web interface of that bucket should indicate "active". However, I am struggling to find a suitable solution to get this "active" status from AWS.

One of my attempts was to use the AWS CLI to check the last modified value of each file in each bucket, but this solution doesn't seem to work after 999+ files. Has anyone tried something like this or can give me a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. To overcome the issue of **999+** objects limit, you'll need to implement pagination in your API calls.
2. Create lambda function, which get triggered upon `s3:fileUpload`. Further you can write status to db and check using query whenever required.